# htaccess doesn't rewrite index.php in Kohana

Tags: .htaccess, kohana

i made search of my problem in google and did not find any useful information.

So everything was ok before i removed the site to other host. this worked well

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

but when i removed the site to other host the index.php doesn't rewrite anymore.

apache version on the host is 2.2.22

file structure when i log in to ftp is /htdocs/and site files.

when i write on browser

```
    http://verana.ge/index/page
```

it gives me 404 error

but on

```
    http://verana.ge/index.php/index/page/
```

works well

bootstrap configuration is this :

```
     'base_url'   => '/',
     'index_file' => FALSE,
```

so please help me and tell me if i do something wrong or it is apache configuration problem or it is Kohana's problem

Thank you in advance

ADDED

One more details

i contacted to sys admin of my host and he gave me log file which says

```
     /var/www/virtual/verana.ge/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteLog not allowed here
```

on the same host i have wordpress site and its htaccess file lokes like this and works

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /college/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /college/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

can you tell me please where is and what is the problem

ADDED

rewrite log says

```
    [verana.ge/sid#21cbdd98][rid#21e0ad78/initial] (3) [perdir /var/www/virtual/verana.ge/htdocs/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/virtual/verana.ge/htdocs/ ->
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you check if .htaccess is even being run? Insert some random string of characters somewhere and see if you get a 500 error when you load a page.

Comment: Thank you for your replay, yes i got 500 error when i put some random string

Comment: Hmm, then add two lines to do logging of rewrites and see what's happening there. Line 1: RewriteLog "/usr/local/apache/logs/rewrite.log" Line 2: RewriteLogLevel 4 make sure to change the path of the log file, make sure the path exists and the file exists and is writable by the web user.

Comment: .htaccess file is in htdocs directory and there i created the file named by rewrite.log and in htaccess file on the bottom i added this lines RewriteLog "/rewrite.log" and RewriteLogLevel 4 and i got 500 error

Comment: Give the full (system) path to RewriteLog and if it still throws a 500 error, check your web server logs to see what the error is.

Comment: do you mean in (system) path this "/htdocs/rewrite.log" when my upper directory is htdocs. i have no full control of this host i can control only my ftp directory. is it right path in case when my upper directory is htdocs

Comment: No I mean the full system path to the file on the machine this is hosted, even if it is a hosting company.

Comment: it is host company and i don't know system path. i will contact them and they will make debug it and when will get log file i will post back this log file

Comment: If you run phpinfo() in a file, it should show you the path as well.

Comment: thank you, path is not problem. on the top i added more details but still no answer.

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem.

so my apache server version is 2.2.22 and i did htaccess file like following:

```
 IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
 /IfModule>
```

now this htaccess conficuration for apache 2.2.22 works well